# Can static_assert check if a type is a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

Can static_assert check if a type is a vector? IE, an `int` would raise the assertion, whereas a `vector<int>` would not.
I'm thinking of something along the lines of:

```
static_assert(decltype(T) == std::vector, "Some error")
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. Consider the following meta function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

template <class N>
struct is_vector { static const int value = 0; };

template <class N, class A>
struct is_vector<std::vector<N, A> > { static const int value = 1; };

int main()
{
   printf("is_vector<int>: %d\n", is_vector<int>::value);
   printf("is_vector<vector<int> >: %d\n", is_vector<std::vector<int> >::value);
}
```

Simply use that as your expression in `static_assert`.

Comment: Keep in mind it may also have an allocator type different from the default.

Comment: @sharptooth: or a typedef with `boost::true_type` and `false_type`.

Comment: @GMan: Is there a way to address that case?

Comment: @sharptooth: The allocator is just another template parameter. So the first specialization could be something like `template<class N, class A> struct is_vector< std::vector<N, A> > { ... }` which should cover all cases, including the allocator.

Comment: @In silico: will they all be auto-deduced?

Comment: @sharptooth: I don't see why not. I've successfully tested it on VC++ 9.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: or inherit from `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`.  That is why they were included in the c++0x.

Answer (score 10):

c++0x:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<T, std::vector<int>>::value, "Some Error");
```

Comment: But what if the vector was a char vector, which I also want to accept along with int vectors?

Comment: Isn't `std::is_same` a `C++11` thing ?

Comment: @Shreevardhan "C++0x" means the same thing as "C++11"

Comment: @小太郎: You would have to check `std::is_same<T, std::vector<typename T::value_type>>`. Of course, if `T` is _not_ a vector, it might not even have a `value_type`.

Answer (score 3):

A general solution. Given a type, and a template, to check if the type is an instance of the latter:

```
template<typename T, template<typename...> class Tmpl>
struct is_instance_of_a_given_class_template : std:: false_type {};
template<template<typename...> class Tmpl, typename ...Args>
struct is_instance_of_a_given_class_template< Tmpl<Args...>, Tmpl > : std:: true_type {};
```

With this, then the following will be true:

```
is_instance_of_a_given_class_template<    vector<int>  ,  vector  > :: value
                    type to check  ~~~~~~~^               ^
        template to check against  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/
```

and therefore you would use:

```
static_assert( is_instance_of_a_given_class_template<T,std::vector>::value
              , "Some error")
```

*Note:* If `T` is `const`, this won't work directly. So test for something like `is_instance_of_a_given_class_template< std::decay_t<T> ,std::vector>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

```
template<typename T>
struct isVector
{
  typedef char (&yes)[2];
  template<typename U>
  static yes check(std::vector<U>*);
  static char check(...);

  static const bool value = (sizeof(check((T*)0)) == sizeof(yes));
};
```

Usage:

```
isVector<vector<int> >::value;
isVector<int>::value;
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/tOU5n).

**Note**: My (complicated) answer has a limitation that it evaluates to `true` if if `T` is publically inherited from `vector<>`. It *might* result in compiler error if T has `private`/`protected` inheritance from `vector<>`. Just keeping it for record, that this way should not be used !! :)